# Who wrote that the role of a government is to protect from foreign threats, promote trade, and provide for those that cannot provide for themselves?

Tags: political-theory, government, history, reference-request

Who wrote that the role of a government is to protect from foreign threats, promote trade, and provide for those that cannot provide for themselves (physically or cognitively impaired)?

The description comes from a conversation a few years ago with a co-worker about the importance of dealing with politics in all facets of life. We were specifically talking about office politics in an organization of over 100k employees.

He pulled some examples from some books written a long time ago. I say a long time ago instead of some specific time frame because I don't exactly recall. If pressed I'd say around when Plato lived. I've verified that the idea exists and it came from some ancient philosopher but I can't remember which philosopher and which book it was from.

Comment: Sounds more like Hobbes or Locke than an ancient philosopher.

Comment: Yes, as stated this has the air of the "enlightenment" period. Of course some people might consider that "ancient" now. I don't recognize the specific quote or idea.

Comment: If it helps I think it was exactly THREE reasons why governments exists. It was probably worded differently as well.

Comment: It most certainly was not Locke. Nor any of the founders of the US.  The idea of a govt providing for "those who cannot provide for themselves" is a late 19th century or later idea. Probably the first govt that did it to any extent was under Bismark round-about 1870s or later. The founders of the US would be what you would find on a search for "not yours to give."

Comment: Adam Smith lays out three roles of government in his 1776 work The Wealth of Nations, which are similar to the three you mention but not quite a match (he says 'protect from threats', 'administer justice', and 'fund public works'). Perhaps whoever said your three roles was referencing or commenting on Smith's work?

Comment: "provide for those that cannot provide for themselves" This is the tricky one and probably makes it post-Enlightenment. I hunted for figures as late a Churchill saying that and couldn't find it, so I'm thinking 20th century.